# Attempt to index a nil value

Tags: dictionary, lua, lua-table

Beginner to Lua (and programming) here. I'm trying to create a table and fill it with random integers, but I keep getting the "attempt to index a nil value" error. I had previously neglected to define the table map, so when I searched around here, I found that solution and added in `map = { }`. Unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue.

I suspect that the loop is trying to put random values into an undefined table, and that that is just not possible. How would I then go about putting an arbitrary amount of random numbers into a table?

Here is my code so far:

```
map = { }

for k = 1, 20 do
    for l = 1, 5 do
        map[k][l] = math.random(0,3)
    end
end
```

Comment: Note you can also fill it as a 'flat' array by doing `map[5 * (k - 1) + l]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `map[k]` is initially nil. In order to get the desired result, create a table at that index if one does not already exist:

```
map = { }

for k = 1, 20 do
    for l = 1, 5 do
        if not map[k] then
            map[k] = {}
        end
        map[k][l] = math.random(0,3)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would offer a simpler version:

```
map = { }

for k = 1, 20 do
    map[k] = {}    
    for l = 1, 5 do
        map[k][l] = math.random(0,3)
    end
end
```